# Embed wikitude browser in phonegap app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, wikitude

The [wikitude camera phonegap plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WikitudeCamera) requires the user to install separately the wikitude browser. Is it possible to embed the browser in an app to skip this install step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin is based on the old Wikitude API using Android intents to launch Wikitude. This API has been deprecated. In case phonegap is not super important for you at the moment you can use the Wikitude SDK (sdk.wikitude.com), which works stand-alone without the Wikitude app installed.

Wikitude SDK as a phonegap plugin will be available soon.

Disclaimer: I'm working for Wikitude.

Comment: Refining to that - Wikitude now offers a plugin for PhoneGap, where you can include the Wikitude SDK to any of your PhoneGap projects. Details can be found on the [Wikitude website](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/sdk/phonegap-plugin) and on GitHub [Android](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/AugmentedReality-Wikitude) and [iOS](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/AugmentedReality-Wikitude)

Comment: The location of the GitHub repository moved and now can be found at: [https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap](https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap) for both Android and iOS. Also [documentation](http://developer.wikitude.com/documentation/phonegap) has been substantially updated.